# How do I write array in XML? YML-XML translation

Tags: xml, symfony

I have this yml code

```
my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
    class:  HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
    arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager,{facebook: facebook_id, google: google_id}]
```

However I have to translate this into XML, so I made this code.

I have one question.

```
     <service id="my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service" class="HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider">
     <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager">

      {facebook: facebook_id, google: google_id}  #How do I write array in XML?

     </service>
```

How do I write an array in XML??

Comment: I think you mixed XML and YML in your question, please update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second argument would be something like:

```
<argument type="collection">
    <argument key="facebook">facebook_id</argument>
    <argument key="google">google_id</argument>
</argument>
```

Comment: Thanks,I should use 'key'!